# How to prevent ordering of json string during parsing using groovy jsonslurper?

Tags: groovy, jsonslurper

I have a josn string like below,

```
def input = '''{"name":"abul","age":30,"street":"Uttara"}'''
```

After parsing json string **input** like below,

```
def output = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(input)
```

I got following value of **output**

```
'''{"age":30,"name":"abul","street":"Uttara"}'''
```

But I expect no change in order i.e, expected result is

```
  {"name":"abul","age":30,"street":"Uttara"}
```

How can I do using same lib i.e, **groovy.json.JsonSlurper**

Comment: What are you trying to do? compare? something else?

Comment: I am processing json response to modify. I need to parse but after parsing using "groovy.json.JsonSlurper" got ordered output that is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't.

If you want ordering, you'll have to use a json array.

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value pairs,
>   where a name is a string and a value is a string, number, boolean,
>   null, object, or array.
>
> An array is an ordered sequence of zero or more values.
>
> Reference : http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt